# C# -Getting Possible pairs from two enums

Tags: c#, linq

From two enums ,what is the way to apply LINQ to get pairs

like

{Red,Car},{Red,Bike},{Green,Car},{Green,Bike},...

```
public enum Color
{
    Red,Green,Blue
}

public enum Vehicle
{
    Car,Bike
}
```

can i use something like

```
var query = from c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Color)).AsQueryable() 
            from c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Vehicle)).AsQueryable()    
            select new {..What to fill here?.. }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `c` as the range variable twice, don't use `AsQueryable` unless you really need to, use an anonymous type in a really simple way, and specify the type of the range variable to avoid problems due to Enum.GetValues just returning `Array`:

```
var query = from Color c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Color))
            from Vehicle v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Vehicle))
            select new { Color = c, Vehicle = v };
```

(That's equivalent to calling `.Cast<Color>` and `.Cast<Vehicle>` on the respective `Enum.GetValues` calls.)

Then you can write it out like this:

```
foreach (var pair in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{{{0}, {1}}}", pair.Color, pair.Vehicle);
}
```

Comment: Senor Speed! Corrected the casting issue before I finished typing.

Comment: :) Actually I do not know what is the actual use of AsQueryable.I skipped that chapter from your book.I have to read it.

Comment: @threadpool: Cast/OfType: It depends if you want to skip values of different types or throw an exception. If they really *should* be the expected type (i.e. anything else represents a bug) then use Cast. As for indexing - you can use dot notation and a different overload of Select - unfortunately I don't have time to show an example right now. You may want to ask that as a different question so that someone else can answer it.